# Graph Theory - The 'Delivery Problem'

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I have come up with a problem that can be modelled using graph theory. I tend to refer to it as the 'Delivery Problem'. I am asking whether there exists a similar problem to the one I am about to present and / or algorithms that could solve it or could play a role in solving it.

Suppose there is a courier carrying a set of items; each item has an identification and an amount. Also suppose there is a set of storages that the courier can go to. Each storage can only store items that have certain identifications. Furthermore, storages have a maximum amount they can store - a capacity. The identifications accepted and capacity are arbitrary for every storage. Upon the courier reaching a storage, all items that can fit into it are transferred from the courier.

A little more formally, suppose a weighted, complete graph G in which all vertices represent a storage; V0 is a storage that accepts no items and is the starting location of the courier. A solution is a path in which the maximum amount of items is transferred. An optimal solution is the shortest path in which the maximum amount of items is transferred.

I am looking for an algorithm that can yield sub-optimal solutions, if possible in reasonable time complexity. Could you refer me to any similar problems? algorithms I should take a look at?

Comment: This sounds like a [network flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_network) problem.

Comment: I do not think that the edges have limited capacity; only the vertices can store a limited amount.

Comment: @Théophile Posing it as a network flow problem: Every edge has the same limited capacity which is the courier's items left. The limited capacity would change every time the courier passes a vertex. Thank you for pointing me in that direction, however, I would find difficulties in describing it as a network flow problem. It is indeed only the vertices with a limited capacity, not the edges. Though maybe you would pose it in another way than I described?

Comment: Ah, I see. Maybe there is a simpler way: how about running a shortest path algorithm that keeps track of the goods delivered? So where the usual algorithm just stores the distance $d$ to a vertex, you would store the pair $(d,g)$ where $g$ are the goods remaining. Replace a path that yields $(d_1,g_1)$ with one that yields $(d_2,g_2)$ if the latter is lexicographically smaller, i.e., if $d_2 < d_1$ or if $d_2=d_1$ and $g_2 < g_1$. Does that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unlikely that this is possible in a time complexity that you consider reasonable, because some problems that resemble the travelling salesman problem very closely can be modeled as special cases of your problem.

Let a travelling salesman problem be given by specifying a finite number of grid points to visit on the infinite grid of all points with integer $(x,y)$-coordinates, and such that paths run along the vertical and horizontal lines defined by one of the coordinates being a fixed integer.

This is the same as having $n$ items with amount $1$ each, and $n$ storage points corresponding to the stops of the travelling salesman, each having the capacity to store a total amount of $1.$ The graph is the obvious one formed by the vertical and horizontal unit line segments connecting the points of the infinite grid. If you want a finite graph, limit yourself to a rectangle that contains the $n$ destinations.